# Why does the allPerms function in R always give one combination less?

Tags: r, permutation, permute

I am trying to find all possible combinations for a number ie essentially the factorial of the number but also have display all possible combinations.

When I use the allPerms function I am supposed to get all possible combinations but it gives always one combination less. Why is this so?

```
library(permute)
allPerms(3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    2
[2,]    2    1    3
[3,]    2    3    1
[4,]    3    1    2
[5,]    3    2    1

allPerms(4)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    2    4    3
 [2,]    1    3    2    4
 [3,]    1    3    4    2
 [4,]    1    4    2    3
 [5,]    1    4    3    2
 [6,]    2    1    3    4
 [7,]    2    1    4    3
 [8,]    2    3    1    4
 [9,]    2    3    4    1
[10,]    2    4    1    3
[11,]    2    4    3    1
[12,]    3    1    2    4
[13,]    3    1    4    2
[14,]    3    2    1    4
[15,]    3    2    4    1
[16,]    3    4    1    2
[17,]    3    4    2    1
[18,]    4    1    2    3
[19,]    4    1    3    2
[20,]    4    2    1    3
[21,]    4    2    3    1
[22,]    4    3    1    2
[23,]    4    3    2    1
```

As you can see the very first combinations of 123 and 1234 for both the cases is missing respectively.

I know I can get all possible combinations using the permn() function from combinat package.

I just wanted to know if there is a way to use allPerms itself for this purpose. Or any other function too. Any info on this will be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: from [the manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/permute/permute.pdf): seems like `allPerms(4, control = how(complete = TRUE))` should work. strange that `complete` is `FALSE` by default...

Comment: @MichaelChirico Even if I use the control = how(complete =TRUE) it still gives the same result.

Comment: The manual also states `permute`'s description: "A set of restricted permutation designs for freely exchangeable, line transects (time series),
and spatial grid designs plus permutation of blocks (groups of samples) is provided." It seems it's not necessarily designed to be used in this way; what's wrong with `permn`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes the definition does say so. Its just the results of permn is always stored columnwise and not rowwise which I find it difficult to handle. Else it works absolutely fine.

Comment: also, it appears `permn` is written all in R -- you could simply repurpose the code yourself to output the transpose: https://github.com/cran/combinat/blob/master/R/permn.R

Comment: @MichaelChirico `complete = TRUE` is a flag to force complete enumeration - it doesn't really have any side effect when used with `allPerms` as you are intentionally asking for all the permutations (complete enumeration). As to why `allPerms` works they way it does, I've included a note about that in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes transpose works fine in this case.. Thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the `observed` flag to `TRUE` using the `how()` helper function.

```
h <- how(observed = TRUE)
allPerms(3, h)

> h <- how(observed = TRUE)
> allPerms(3, h)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    1    3    2
[3,]    2    1    3
[4,]    2    3    1
[5,]    3    1    2
[6,]    3    2    1
```

Why is `observed = FALSE` the default? Well, this is intentional because the entire package was designed from the viewpoint of restricted permutation tests that are common in applied uses of ordination methods in ecology. Given that we already have the observed permutation, the data, we don't want it in the permutations used to define the null distribution of the test statistic; well we do, but only through the observed data, not any extra ones that might come up during permutation.

Comment: thanks! i got the feeling from poking around documentation this package wasn't designed with this sort of task as a main priority. +1